# Is it possible to parametrize Java Aspect

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

Is it possible to parametrize an Aspect? Right now I have an @Integration Aspect and my pointcuts are like:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(Integration)",returning = "result")
```

So, wherever it finds @Integration, it will call this method.  Can I implement something like this:

```
@Integration("new") or @Integration("deleted"),
```

to avoid to create new annotation for every case?

Also, if this is possible, how to access this provided value ("new" or "deleted").

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it's possible
2. Here is [description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) of how to add a value to your annotation
3. Here is the [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-aopwork8/) full of examples of annotation processing with AspectJ; e.g. Listing 8 shows how to access your annotation value inside of aspect

Comment: Thanks again. I also found this great article: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/